# file put contents with array

Tags: php

I am using `file_put_contents($file, $data);` function for putting contents in file, because these files are created on fly with name of sessions, **$data** is an multi-dimensional array, when i am echoing array it prints out fine but in file no contents get recorded except the word **Array**

What should i do or is there any other function which automatically creates the file and records the data (array)?

Thank You.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You want to `serialize()` the array on writting, and `unserialize()` after reading the file.

```
$array = array('foo' => 'bar');
file_put_contents('foo.txt', serialize($array));
$array = unserialize(file_get_contents('foo.txt')));
```

Oh, and I really don't now how you echo'd your array, but `echo array('foo' => 'bar');` will always print `Array`.

Comment: i am sorry for using the wrong term, but i am using print_r for displaying my array

Comment: just a note, your missing a ) on the 2nd line

Comment: another note, there is an additional bracket at the end of the 3rd line

Answer (score 13):

Or use [print_r](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) if you want to return a formatted array that is more easily readable in the txt file

> If you would like to capture the output of print_r(), use the return
> parameter. When this parameter is set to TRUE, [print_r()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) will return
> the information rather than print it.

Code is:

```
$txt = "<pre>".print_r($data, true)."</pre>";
file_put_contents('file.txt', $txt);
```

Comment: I'm not sure the `<pre>` is necessary. There was nothing about this being outputted to an HTML file. That said, if it was, yes, that's perfectly reasonable. Might be worth adding a note about, at least. (And you should link [`print_r`'s documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) so people can learn about what it does)

Answer (score 6):

If you want it to be readable, you could do:

```
<?php
ob_start();
print_r($data);
$textualRepresentation = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

file_put_contents($file, $textualRepresentation);
?>
```

Comment: $textualRepresentation = print_r($data, true); would just do fine :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could [serialize](https://www.php.net/serialize) the array and then userialize it after you load the file back in. You could also encode the array as a JSON object with [json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and write to a .json file.

Answer (score 1):

Definetelly you can use [var_export](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) function:

```
$contents = var_export($array, true);

file_put_contents('foo.txt', "<?php\n return {$contents};\n ?>");
// and then use something like this to get it:
$new_array = require('foo.txt');
```

Answer (score 1):

A better solution if you are familiar with `var_dump()` output could be to capture it's output and put it into the file, or even `print_r()` as follow:

```
ob_start();
print_r($array);
$result = ob_get_clean();
file_put_contents('file.txt', $result);
```

note the `ob_get_clean()` essentially executes both `ob_get_contents()` and `ob_end_clean()`.

Answer (score 0):

As the best answer states, using `serialize` is a good option. However, you can also store the array by using `PHP_EOL` after each item of the array and use the `file` command to retrieve the array.

```
function file_put_array($path, $contents)
{
    if (is_array($contents))
    {
        foreach ($contents as $item)
            $str .= $item.PHP_EOL;
        file_put_contents($path, $str);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

And to retreive the contents:

```
$contents = file($path, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can set up a recursive function that can traverse each member of an array, check if it is itself an array, and if so call the function again on this member, and if not just print out its contents.  Like this:

```
function file_put_contents_deep( $file, $data) {
  if ( is_array( $data ) {
    foreach ( $data as $item ) {
      if (is_array( $item ) {
        file_put_contents_deep( $file, $item );
      else {
        file_put_contents( $file, $item);
      }
    }
  } else {
    file_put_contents( $file, $data );
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$content="< ?php"."\r\n";
$str = json_encode($array);
$content.="$";
$content.="list=json_decode('";
$content.=$str;
$content.="');";
$ds=DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
file_put_contents(__DIR__ . $ds . 'list.php', $content);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please add some detail to your question and format it correctly.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See:  [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks.